# How $\langle f,\phi\rangle_{L^2} = 0 \ (\le0)$ implies $f = 0 \ (\le0)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, partial-differential-equations

I was reading a paper where I found a statement that if $f$ is some function in $L^2(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is an open subset of say $\mathbb R^d, d\ge2$, then

> $f = 0 \ (\le0)$ in an open subset $A$ of $\Omega$ if $\langle
>  f,\phi\rangle_{L^2} = 0 \ (\le0)$ for all $\phi\in H_0^1(A)$ (with
>   $\phi\ge0$).

I am not getting how to solve this as to get $f=0$ is quite visible but that too only if I take $\phi\in \mathbb D(A)$.

Please suggest way on how to proceed with this

Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Also, use `$\langle X\rangle$` for $\langle X\rangle$.

Comment: This may be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations

Comment: sorry @DaniloGregorin it is not because here we are working on $\phi \ge 0$

Comment: I am the one to say sorry, for not noting this.

Comment: @bunny see my new answer

Answer (score 2):

So, if I understood correctly you want to prove: $$
\big\{\langle f,\phi\rangle =0 , \ \forall \phi \in L^2(A), \ \phi\geq 0 \ \hbox{in } A\big\} \quad \implies \quad f\equiv 0.
$$
In fact, let's proceed by contradiction. So, assume that $\langle f,\phi\rangle=0$ for all positive $\phi\in L^2(A)$ but that $f\neq 0$ a.e.. Thus, there exists a Lebesgue point $x_0\in A$ such that $f(x_0)=c\neq 0$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, consider a sequence of positive functions $\phi_n \in C^\infty_0(A)$ with supports satisfying $$
\mathrm{supp}(\phi_n)=(x_0-\tfrac{2}{n},x_0+\tfrac{2}{n}).$$
Additionally, suppose that $\phi'(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\leq x_0$, $\phi'(x)\leq 0$ for all $x\geq x_0$ and $$
\forall x\in (x_0-\tfrac{1}{n},x_0+\tfrac{1}{n}), \quad  \phi(x)\equiv \tfrac{n}{2},
$$
(basically, $\phi_n$ is a family of bump functions shrinking to $x_0$). Then, by Lebesgue's differentiation Theorem (notice that here we are using the fact that $x_0$ is a Lebesgue point) we conclude
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\langle f,\phi_n\rangle=f(x_0)\neq 0.
$$
Hence, by continuity of the inner product (since $f\in L^2$ and $\{\phi_n\}\subset L^2$), for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large such that for all integer $n\geq N$ we have $$
f(x_0)+\varepsilon\geq \langle f,\phi_n\rangle \geq f(x_0)-\varepsilon
$$
Hence, by taking $\varepsilon$ small enough we obtain a contradiction. Thus, $f\equiv 0$.

**Edit:** Notice that the proof shows that there is no need to consider the set of test functions to be $H^1_0$. It is enough to assume that the property holds for any function $\phi\in C_0^\infty(A)$, which of course is a strict subset of $H_0^1(A)$, which at the same time is a strict subset of $L^2$.

Comment: $\phi$ is taken to be positive

Comment: @DaniloGregorin yep

Comment: Sorry, I had only read the beginning of your answer.

Comment: i suppose that this proof will work even when we have given $\langle f,\phi\rangle \le0$, i just have one query that why did you choose your $\phi_n=\frac{2}{n}$, infact I suppose we can work with $\phi_n=1$ in $(x_0-\frac{1}{n},x_0+\frac{1}{n})$

Comment: Yes, the bigger interval has "no relevance" for my argument. The main point is that $\phi_n(x)=A$ in $(x_0-\tfrac{1}{n},x_0+\tfrac{1}{n})$, where $A$ is exactly the length of that interval.The idea ofconsidering a second bigger interval is to be able to make $\phi_n$ **smooth** and compactly supported(it cannot have jumps).  Notice that on the other answer Danilo is not working with smooth function, so his answer strongly depends on being able to assume the property for all test function $\phi\in L^2$ (not only in $H^1_0$ but in $L^2$, because $\phi_+,\phi_-$ have no integrable weak derivativ)

Comment: no my question is why do we need to fix $\phi(x)=A$ in (x_0-\frac{1}{n},x_0+\frac{1}{n}) where $A$ is the length of the interval, why can not we take it to some constant  say $A=1$ throughout because if we take $\phi(x)=A$ where $A$ is the length of the interval, and $\phi$ is compactly supported in (x_0-\frac{2}{n},x_0+\frac{2}{n}) then $\phi_n$ seems to be going to $0$ only right

Comment: @bunny Oh, sorry, my bad. I wanted to say $\tfrac{n}{2}$. You are totally right. The idea of the trick is to be able to write the inner product $\langle f,\phi_n\rangle$ in terms of Lebesgue's differentiation Theorem.Take a look of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Comment: I just wanted to add that after talking with Danilo I've convinced myself that his answer is 100% ok, no problem with the test functions (I cannot edit my previous comment).

Answer (score 1):

An attempt. Tell me what you think.

If equality holds for every $\phi$ positive, it also holds for every negative $\phi$ (just multiply by $-1$). Let $\phi$ change sign. Write $\phi = \phi^+ + \phi^-$. We know that

$$
\int_A f(\phi^+ - \phi^-) \ dx = 0 \implies \int_A f \phi^+ \ dx = \int_A f \phi^- \ dx. = 0. 
$$
Hence 
$$
\int_A f \phi \ dx = 0 \quad \forall \phi \in H_0^1(A).
$$

Since the equality holds for every $\phi \in C_c^\infty(A)$ and this space is dense in $L^2$, and since the functional $g \mapsto \int_A f(x) g(x) \ dx$ is continuous in $L^2$,we have that 
$$
\int_A f(x) g(x) \ dx = 0 \quad \forall g \in L^2(A).
$$

Putting $g = f$ yields the result.

Comment: but this is not given to be true for all $\phi$ in $H_0^1(A)$ it is given for those $\phi$ such that $\phi \ge0$

Comment: Sorry, my bad not noting this

Comment: Oh, it's quite nice your answer (much shorter than mine). The only thing it's not clear for me is that $\phi_+$ and $\phi_-$ belong to $H^1$. Basically, you would have to differentiate a characteristic function. Wouldn't that give a $\delta$ function on the derivative?

Comment: I did not give very deep thoughts about this, let me think.

Comment: Take $\phi^+$ for example. Couldn't we approximate it as a sum of mollifiers convoluted with positive functions in $C_c^\infty(A)$ with disjoint supports?

Comment: @Sharik what do you think?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin it seems weird to me because at the end you even consider $g=f$, but $f$ is only in $L^2$. So I am not sure that you can consider $g=f$ since it has to be on $H^1$. But the idea is quite cool, just I am not 100% sure how to complete it.

Comment: Also, are we really using that the positive and negative parts belong to $H_0^1(A)$? It suffices that they belong to $L^2$, no?

Comment: @Sharik at the end we are using that $C_c^\infty(A)$ is dense in $L^2$

Comment: @DaniloGregorin That's the main point. That you are assuming that it's zero testing against a strictly smaller set than the set where your initial function belongs to. Otherwise, if you assume that you have a function $f\in L^2$ with the property of being orthogonal to all other function in $L^2$, then it's immediately zero (without the necessity of these proofs).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107108/discussion-between-danilo-gregorin-and-sharik).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already know that if $g\geq 0$ and $\int g\,dx=0$, then $g=0$ (btw, all these equalities and inequalities are to be understood in the almost everywhere sense).

I think the cleanest way to prove this is the following: Both claims would follow easily from the fact mentioned above if we could test with all $\phi\in L^2$. For the first claim we would take $\phi=f$ and for the second $\phi=f_+$.

Herewe are not allowed to take all $\phi\in L^2$, but we can still approximate. Of course $H^1_0$ is dense in $L^2$ (because it contains $C_c^\infty$), but the nonnegative functions in $H^1_0$ are also dense in the nonnegative functions in $L^2$. In fact, if $\phi\in H^1_0$, then $\phi_\pm\in H^1_0$, and if $\phi_n\to \phi$ in $L^2$, then $\phi_n^\pm\to \phi^\pm$ in $L^2$. I'll leave the last statement as an exercise (hint: $\nabla \phi_+=1_{\{\phi>0\}}\nabla \phi$).

Now if $f\in L^2$ and $\phi_n\in H^1_0$ such that $\phi_n\to f$, then
$$
\langle f,f\rangle_2=\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle f,\phi_n\rangle_2=0
$$
in the first case, and
$$
\langle f_+,f_+\rangle_2=\langle f,f_+\rangle_2=\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle f,\phi_n^-\rangle_2\leq 0
$$
in the second case.